# How to prove Exponential is monotone?

Tags: real-analysis

How can you prove that if given $x>y$ implies $e^x >e^y$ ?

Comment: What is your definition of the exponential function? the answer we will give will highly depend on your definition!

Comment: Power series definition only .

Comment: sorry x and y are real.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the power series definition, it is clear that $e^t>1$ for $t>0$.

Take $x>y$ and let $t=x-y>0$. Then $e^{x-y}=e^t>1$, which implies $e^x=e^{x-y} e^y > e^y$.

This assumes that you have proved $e^{a+b}=e^a e^b$.

Comment: But how will you prove that $e^(a+b)=e^ae^b$.

Comment: @Bob, one way is to prove that $e^x$ is the only solution of $f'(x)=f(x), f(0)=1$. It all really depends on the order you do things.

Comment: But how can you prove that it is the unique solution and f(0)=1

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

\begin{align} e^x-e^y&=\left(1+x+\frac{1}{2!}x^2+\frac{1}{3!}x^3+\ldots \right) - \left(1+y+\frac{1}{2!}y^2+\frac{1}{3!}y^3+\ldots \right) \\
&=\left(x-y\right)+\frac{1}{2!}\left(x^2-y^2\right)+\frac{1}{3!}\left(x^3-y^3\right)+\ldots  \end{align}